# What gives Raktajino its kick?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon, food

Does Raktajino contain caffeine or some other stimulant? How potent is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Caffeine

In the DS9 episode ["...Nor the Battle to the Strong"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/502.htm), Quark creates a **decaffeinated** version;

> **ODO:** (re: the drink) *What is it?*
>
> **QUARK:** (pleased with himself) ***The chief asked me to come up with a decaffeinated raktajino for Kira.*** I'm thinking of marketing it.
>
> All watch as Kira takes a sip from the mug...
>
> **WORF:** *Well...?*
>
> **KIRA:** (grimacing) *Ugh... it's awful.*

The implication (based on observation) is that it contains a **lot** of caffeine.

Comment: Of course it's awful! It's DECAF!

Comment: @natewatson - I was intrigued to find out the other day that decaf coffee can still contains as much caffeine as a can of coke

Comment: Decaf is horrible, because it's false product labeling most of the time. It's also a horrible concept, but that's another matter.