# Is Raktajino Klingon like a bat'leth or Klingon like Shakespeare?

Tags: star-trek, languages, klingon

In DS9, Trials and Tribble-ations, Odo says that raktajino is a 'Klingon coffee'.

My question is: is  raktajino made from a Klingon native plant species or substance that is *similar but not related to* to the Earth fruit we call coffee (and also contains caffeine: see [What gives Raktajino its kick?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92468/what-gives-raktajino-its-kick)) or did Klingons take, as they did with Shakespeare, the Earth plant *Coffea arabica* (or similar) and adapt it to make their own variety of the beverage we know as coffee?

Comment: Everyone knows that that Earth version of ratkajino, "coffee", is just a ripoff perpetrated by envious, weak, pathetic Terrans.

Comment: It's a combination of the Earth drink coffee with a Klingon drink called "rak'taj". The Klingons invented it, so technically it's a Klingon drink.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is answered in [Klingon for the Galactic Traveler](https://books.google.com/books?id=9Vz1q4p87GgC&lpg=PT76&ots=fqBuBij-9y&dq=%22raktajino%22%20%22plant%22&pg=PT76#v=onepage&q=%22raktajino%22%20%22plant%22&f=false) by [Marc Okrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Okrand).  (Marc invented modern Klingon.)

> Though **not native to the Empire**, Klingons have developed a way to make
> coffee (**qa'vIn**) (*caffiene*?) particularly strong, both in flavor and in its effect
> as a stimulant, and it is a very popular beverage.
>
> As a rule, coffee is consumed plain—that is, black—but some
> Klingons prefer to mix other ingredients in with the coffee. If some
> kind of HIq (liquor) is added to the coffee, the drink is called
> **ra’taj**. It is said that the drink was originally nicknamed ra’wI’ taj
> (commander's knife, suggestive of its potency), and that the name was
> shortened over time. This often repeated story cannot be confirmed. In
> any event, ra’taj became one of the few Klingon foods to become
> popular outside of the Empire, though in an altered form. Instead of
> containing liquor, as does the genuine Klingon ra’taj, the "export"
> version (which came to be pronounced **raktaj** in Federation Standard)
> consists of strong Klingon coffee plus a nut-like flavoring.
> Eventually, a new fashion developed—adding cream to the raktaj—and
> with this innovation came yet another name, **raktajino**, modeled after
> the name of another popular coffee drink, cappuccino. Raktajino is now
> served hot or iced, with or without extra cream, and with or without
> the rind of some fruit to add even more flavor. Though it is sometimes
> called Klingon coffee, it is quite different from both plain qa’vIn
> and the alcoholic ra’taj.

Comment: So, the Klingons imported Earth coffee, mixed it with alcohol, then re-exported a non-alcoholic version of it called "raktaj" that got mixed with milk to make the "raktajino"?

Comment: @nick012000:   Yes, that's what they said.... ?